# Using qgrep and -e doesn't give what I want

Tags: grep

I'm using a windows version of `grep` (`qgrep`) and I'm using the `-e` argument and I'm not getting what I want.

I have a router log file that I'm trying to process and specifically I have:

```
SRC=18.x.x.x
```

or

```
SRC=18y.x.x.x
```

The log file has many different `SRC=a.b.c.d`, but I'm just focusing here where the source IP starts with `18`.

The output I want is `18.x.x.x` (ie just the `18.` IP's).

My `qgrep` command is:

```
qgrep -e "SRC=18." source.file destination.file
```

I am using the quotes exactly like I have it on that line.

But `qgrep` is ignoring the `.` and is giving me `18` and `18x` in the output.

Is `grep` or `qgrep` with the `-e` option supposed to ignore the `.` in my argument?

EDIT: Sorry, my `qgrep` command included `SRC=` but I didn't originally have that in my question.

Comment: In addition to what steeldriver said (in a now deleted comment about `.` matching any character), the expression `18\.` would still also match e.g. `10.18.0.0`. You should use an expression that is a bit more strict, e.g. `SRC=18`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I deleted my comment because the help text [here](https://ss64.com/nt/qgrep.html) says *"-e string Treat the next argument as a literal search string."* although I suspect it really *doesn't*. There also appears to be a `-L` switch *"Search strings literally."* which is perhaps equivalent to grep's `-F` ?

Comment: @steeldriver So it's a Window-specific tool then, not a Windows-implementation of the POSIX `grep` utility? Then it's off-topic on this site and should be taken to someplace like SuperUser instead.

Comment: Since my question does pertain to "qgrep" then if there is a spot-on windows stack exchange site for this question then please point me to it.  On the other hand, if the unix grep also behaves the way I'm seeing with qqrep then perhaps the OS-specific implimentation doesn't matter and my question is appropriate here.

Comment: We don't know what qgrep is/does and assuming it behaves the same as some version of grep that runs on Unix isn't useful so you should delete this question and find a Windows forum to ask it on.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about some Windows tool named `qgrep`, not about a Unix tool.

Comment: Would the unix grep command [grep -e "SRC=18." infile > outfile] give me output lines that would include "SRC=182.what-ever" ?  Tell me how unix grep would handle this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346816/using-grep-to-search-for-a-string-that-has-a-dot-in-it  So that's the problem here.  -e is supposed to indicate a literal search string, but the dot or period is still treated differently.

Comment: Actually, in the case of GNU `grep` the `-e` option means "use the following expression as search" and is designed to allow patterns starting with `-` (which otherwise would be mis-interpreted as options), but the argument is still treated as a full regular expression. Here, the option `-F` would mean that the pattern is to be interpreted as literal string.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so just like the unix grep, the grep and qgrep available for windows does not allow for a straight-forward way to include periods (.) in a search string.

So this does work:  grep -e SRC=18[.] *.log > out.txt

No quotes needed, just need to use square brackets around the period.